Which Democratic members of Congress continue to support US military aid to Israel?
A Politico article from April 4th, "A blinking red light for Israel in American politics",
opens with the observation that US leadership is "nearly" out of patience.
The Politico article went on to say something that would've been unimaginable just a few months ago:

A House Democrat who didn’t want to run afoul of the White House added that Biden is “feeling a ton of pressure from outside of his inner circle. Most of us are fed up, and I think the bottom is going to fall out on support for additional Israel security funding, at least in the Democratic caucus.”

Biden speaking to the Israeli PM, again asked Israel to dial it down a bit. However, this isn't the first such request. The killing of aid workers has been going on for months in full view of the media, approaching 200 killed, per the UN Secretary General.
If Netanyahu continues to blow off requests from Biden, the record of US Congressional support or opposition could take on more political significance - especially if the humanitarian crisis continues on the current trend.

Is there any organization (on either side of the issue) tracking where members of US Congress stand on this?

Alternatively, which Democratic members of Congress have taken a stand on the issue, in light of recent developments?



I would wager that before the recent months (and certainly before October) military aid for Israel in Congress was universal. So it would actually be a much smaller list showing which congressmen are opposed to aid. The same can be said for Ukraine, etc.

Most of those killed previously were UNRWA so Palestinians. However with Israel rejecting UNRWA cooperation altogether as supporters of terrorism, the more Western-staffed ones took over. Which is why the WCK strikes killed 1 Palestinian (Dubai resident apparently though), 3 Brits (the 'security team'), 1 US-Canada dual citizen, Australian, 1 Pole. https://edition.cnn.com/2024/04/03/middleeast/world-central-kitchen-workers-gaza-israel-strike-intl/index.html

@thegodsfromengineering - that's certainly part of why the outrage finally broke now. Though Israel has occasionally killed US citizens too, typically young activists of unremarkable origin. The WCK head is apparently in the circle of Biden's courtiers. That's tangential to my interest in action in Congress though. IMO really the only pressure point US policymakers have, that's exposed to the public.

Well, the most criticism seem to come from Jon Stewart. https://youtu.be/RkwgnlPRdHg?t=346 Yeah Bernie Sanders too.

After the Iranian counter-strike that was widely condemned in the West (brilliant move by Netanyahu to copy Trump in Damascus), a lot more Dems no longer have objections to arms aid to Israel than last week. https://www.voanews.com/a/israel-iran-conflict-eases-pressure-on-biden-to-condition-aid/7577207.html Will know the exact numbers in the vote tomorrow.

@thegodsfromengineering - yes, unfortunately. Netanyahu's gambit got the Biden admin to give up the pretense of being interested in Gaza, and if I were to take a wild guess, also to give up ambitions to get rid of Netanyahu personally. The Israel and Ukraine aid deal was already made a while ago I think - I think they were waiting for Zelensky's government to pass the mobilization law to round up the next half million men and kick that can down the road another year.

Many people seem to fall for islamic propaganda, even politicians in Congress or elsewhere.
The kill ratio is ca. 11000 terrorists to ca. 23000 civilians in Gaza until mid April.
This ratio is completely normal - if not even high - for wars in Middle East against terrorists, f.e. the civilian death ratio for the re-conquer of Mosul was in the order of 1 to 4 or worse. The reason of huge delays was claimed to be to avoid civilian casualties in Mosul.
UNRWA members seemed to directly support the terrorists in Gaza, but still Israel most likely did not systematically attack aid workers.

The numbers are in as of 20 April 2024. In the U.S. Senate, all Democrats voted in support of military aid to Israel with the exceptions of two Democrats, Sens. Jeff Merkley and Peter Welch and Independent Sen. Bernie Sanders. Despite those three votes against, all of the other 48 Democrat senators voted in favor.[1]
Military aid to Israel was voted on and approved in the "lower house" of Congress, the House of Representatives. There were 37 of 213 Democrats of who didn't support military aid to Israel but it passed 366 - 58.[2]
The following 37 Democrat House members voted against: Reps. Becca Balint (D-VT), Don Beyer (D-VA), Earl Blumenauer (D-OR), Jamaal Bowman (D-NY), Cori Bush (D-MO), Greg Casar (D-TX), Joaquin Castro (D-TX), Judy Chu (D-CA), Mark DeSaulnier (D-WA), Lloyd Doggett (D-TX), Maxwell Frost (D-FL), John Garamendi (D-CA), Chuy Garcia (D-IL), Al Green (D-TX), Jonathan Jackson (D-IL), Pramila Jayapal (D-WA), Hank Johnson (D-GA), Ro Khanna (D-CA), Dan Kildee (D-MI), Barbara Lee (D-CA), Summer Lee (D-PA), Jim McGovern (D-MA), Mark Pocan (D-WI), Chellie Pingree (D-ME), Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez (D-NY), Ilhan Omar (D-MN), Ayanna Pressley (D-MA), Delia Ramirez (D-IL), Jamie Raskin (D-MD), Mark Takano (D-CA), Rashida Tlaib (D-MI), Bennie Thompson (D-MS), Jill Tokuda (D-HI), Nydia Velazquez (D-NY), Maxine Waters (D-CA) and Bonnie Watson Coleman (D-NJ) voted against the bill.

Sens. Jeff Merkley and Peter Welch and Independent Sen. Bernie Sanders all continue to support defensive aid to Israel.   It's the offensive aid they oppose with respect to the ongoing Gaza operations.

On March the 5th some 30 House Democrats signed a letter to Biden expressing concern at the situation in Gaza and putting forward the view that any attack on Rafah would likely to be a contravention of international law. That is roughly 30 from amongst 212 (I'm not counting Tom Suozzi as he has yet to be sworn in). So there is clearly still support for Israel amongst Democrats.
Of course, the letter was signed before famine, caused by the Israeli blockade, really started to take a hold in Gaza and before Israel killed 7 aid workers, 6 of whom were non-Palestinian and one of who was a US citizen. These events are likely to have swayed a few more Democrats, but I imagine there are probably still many who support Israel.

"Expressing concern" is barely related to "opposing military support for Israel".  Just saying.


Question:
Which Democratic members of Congress continue to support US military aid to Israel?

Short Answer:
There are less than a handful of Democrats who don't support miliary aid to Israel across the executive and legislative branches.  It's really not even being discussed.  The only thing being paused, is certain offensive weapons like the 2000lb bombs and they are only being "paused", until Israel provides a "creditable plan" on how they will use this munition in an urban environment while safeguarding civilians.  Like that is possible.
Longer Answer
Both Democrats and Republicans in Congress and the Senate are strongly pro-Israel.  Almost no American politicians wish to discontinue military aid to Israel, it's not currently being discussed with any seriousness. The Question should read, with creditable American Reports of atrocities, with UN reports suggesting genocide, with Israel claiming their leaders are about to face indictment by the ICC and with numerous Israeli government officials calling for genocide, which pro-Israeli American political leaders wish to curb 2000 lb bombs shipments to Israel unless the Israeli's express a "creditable plan" to avoid civilians.
Almost no American politicians are suggesting eliminating all military aid to Israel in either party; especially defensive aid.  The only thing being "paused" is the 2000 lb bombs. Denying Israel, this invaluable weapon against the densely packed overwhelming civilian urban landscape.   Nothing says targeting Hamas like a weapon which can level a city block (blast radius 35 meters).  Of which the Israeli's have dropped scores of them already.

Eventually:

the House's actions during a rare Saturday session put on display some cracks in what generally is solid support for Israel within Congress. Recent months have seen progressive Democrats express anger with Israel's government and its conduct of the war in Gaza.
Saturday's vote, in which the Israel aid was passed 366-58, had 37 Democrats and 21 Republicans in opposition.

Note that this was after the widely condemned in the West Iranian [counter-]strike on Israel, and its aftermath, all of which may have swayed some votes according to FDD & VOA.
The first source also gives the tally for the Ukraine vote as as 311-112; all of the nays were Republican on that. So at least in Congress overall, aiding Israel is still more popular than aiding  Ukraine, but among the Democrats that trend is reversed.

N.B. related Q posted by someone else as I was writing this https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/87097/constitutionality-of-house-of-congress-passing-separate-bills-and-then-combining#87097  although that one is not about vote tallies.
